# Using Camera API in jellybean

Tags: android, camera, android-4.2-jelly-bean, autofocus

Could anyone provide a sample code for using the Camera API for Android 4.1 and 4.2 as given in this link: [Link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.AutoFocusMoveCallback.html)

I am currently using this code for older versions but it does not work in Jellybean devices

```
AutoFocusCallback myAutoFocusCallback = new AutoFocusCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onAutoFocus(boolean arg0, Camera arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (arg0) {
                if (mPreviewRunning) {
                    mCamera.takePicture(myShutterCallback, mPicture, mPicture);
                }

            } else {
                flKeepClean.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                btnCamera.setEnabled(true);
                side.setEnabled(true);

            }

        }
    };


    ShutterCallback myShutterCallback = new ShutterCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onShutter() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    };
```

[AutoFocusMoveCallback](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.AutoFocusMoveCallback.html)

Comment: What do you mean with "it does not work"? In the takePicture method I would also either pass null for the raw callback, or pass different callbacks for raw and jpeg.

Comment: As per how I understand it, for jellybean devices we need to use the Camera API as pointed out in this link:http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.1.html#Camera

Comment: onAutoFocus always take you to the else block when run on jellybean devices when used like I've done

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late update. The issue was when the device didn't have autofocus. So you need to first check whether the device has autofocus :
boolean focus = getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(       "android.hardware.camera.autofocus");